# Problem with table content

Tags: tables

I have drawn a table of 2 columns and 5 rows.  but because of 2nd row, 2nd column content is long,,, Only half of the table displays. other part is not displayed.. Please help me.....I tried many times but i couldnt find a solution.

This is the code.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption {Methods Of Validation }

\begin{tabular}{| l | l | }
\hline
Validation Example & Explanation \\ \hline
Unit Testing & The testing of a single program\\ \hline
Integration Testing  &  The testing of related Program or units of code. Validates that multiple parts of  the system interact according to the system design. \\ \hline 
System Testing & The testing of an entire system \\ \hline
Acceptance Testing & The testing the mobile app to make sure it Works as what the system requirements indicate \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790932/how-to-wrap-text-in-latex-tables

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm}}` instead of `{l l}`.

Comment: As well as the answer linked above, you might like to read [this online book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) about tables in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tabularx` environment to have multiline cells in the second column. I redefined the `X` type so as to have vertically centred cells, and used the `caption` package (correct vertical spacing between caption ans table) and the `cellspace` package (better vertical spacing betwwen cells):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}%
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption {Methods Of Validation }
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|S{X}|}
\hline
Validation Example & Explanation \\
\hline
Unit Testing & The testing of a single program\\
\hline
Integration Testing & The testing of related Program or units of code. Validates that multiple parts of the system interact according to the system design. \\
\hline
System Testing & The testing of an entire system \\
\hline
Acceptance Testing & The testing the mobile app to make sure it Works as what the system requirements indicate \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Bernard.But it had some problem with cellspace package. But without using packages i successfully could get the result.

Comment: I happens that `cellspace` conflicts/doesn't work well with some other packages. My code alone should work (it does on my system). The `makecell` package can do almost the same thing, unfortunately, it seems to have a problem with `tabularx`.  As a last resort you can use `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}`, but lines of text are no more centred in the cell they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Without any extra packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption {Methods Of Validation }
\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 p{\dimexpr0.7\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
\hline
Validation Example & Explanation \\
\hline
Unit Testing & The testing of a single program\\
\hline
Integration Testing & The testing of related Program or units of code. Validates that multiple parts of the system interact according to the system design. \\
\hline
System Testing & The testing of an entire system \\
\hline
Acceptance Testing & The testing the mobile app to make sure it Works as what the system requirements indicate \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Idea is to avoid using `tabularx` unless it is very necessary.